# How to groupby columns based on respective index of each row?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

[image]

I am not sure how to group by my dataframe. I would like to groupby all the neighbourhoods based on each borough. Can anyone help me figure this out?

the column is like this: borough,  neighbourhood_1,    neighbourhood_2

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0)`?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide sample input and preferred output as text, not as an image, and code for what you've tried so far, to make a [mcve]

Comment: `df.groupby('borough')` would work on higher pandas as well.